# Ansible: how to construct a variable for a FQDN by concatenated with a "." between variable "name" and variable "domain"

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Firstly I am a newbie to Ansible and DevOps in general. Secondly thanks to all of those who contributed to this community making it useful to learn and assist.
My goal is to create a new variable from two dynamic variables. Given the new variable is an FQDN, I need to join the two with a " . " (full stop / period) between the two.

I have the following payload coming in as JSON

```
{
    "extra_vars": {
        "operation": "add",
        "target_subnet": "172.16.10.0",
        "dns_name": "myserver",
        "dns_domain": "itsadomain.com"
    }
}
```

I want Ansible to take the above information and create the variable objectName. objectName is then us to construct a URL to the backend system to possibly check if that objectName is in use.

My latest variation for this particular section of the playbook is as follows:

```
  - set_fact: objectName = {{[dns_name].[dns_domain]}}
  - name: show objectName
    debug: msg={{ objectName }
```

And the response I get is as follows

```
}
    TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/myproject/myplaybook.yml:42
fatal: [ipamapp.mydomain]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: objectName = {{[dns_name].[dns_domain]}}"
}
```

*Note that I have taken the two incoming variables, placed a " . " between them.
I had reviewed other postings like - 29276198 , but I guess mine is a little different as its two dynamic vars and concatenated by using the full stop “ . ” character*

The expected result is that I can then create "myserver.itsadomain.com" for objectName and use that later in the below play

```
  - name: "Build my hostname search URL"
    set_fact:
     search_url_name: "https://ipamapp.mydomain/search.json?name={{objectName}}"
    when:
     - operation_converted == "add"
     - process_request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
- set_fact:
    objectName: "{{ extra_vars.dns_name ~ '.' ~ extra_vars.dns_domain }}"
```

---

The next option is

```yaml
- set_fact:
    objectName: "{{ extra_vars.dns_name }}.{{ extra_vars.dns_domain }}"
```

---

If the items are in a list it's possible to *join* them. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        objectName: "{{ fqdn|join('.') }}"
      vars:
        fqdn:
          - myserver
          - itsadomain
          - com
```

---

**Example.** Given the payload

```yaml
shell> cat extra-vars.json
{
    "extra_vars": {
    "operation": "add",
    "target_subnet": "172.16.10.0",
    "dns_name": "myserver",
    "dns_domain": "itsadomain.com"
    }
}
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    extra-vars.json
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        objectName: "{{ extra_vars.dns_name ~ '.' ~ extra_vars.dns_domain }}"
    - debug:
        var: objectName
    - set_fact:
        objectName: "{{ extra_vars.dns_name }}.{{ extra_vars.dns_domain }}"
    - debug:
        var: objectName
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  objectName: myserver.itsadomain.com

  objectName: myserver.itsadomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @VladimirBotka for the above.
I tried option 1 and option 2, but it would seem that "extra.vars" was not acceptable, rather an unknown variable.
However, a slight modification of Option 1 did work
Working solution was

```
- set_fact:
    objectName: "{{ dns_name ~ '.' ~ dns_domain }}"
```

Comment: You're welcome. It depends on where the data come from. <gently flame=off> See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to avoid ambiguity next time.